# Java & Android Obfuscator Tool Suggestion

Tags: java, android, obfuscation

We develop both Android and Java projects, and we need an *obfuscator tool* with *encryption* ability. Price is not a concern. What can you suggest me? What is the best *obfuscator* that can be used both for Java and Android projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proguard's (java and android, open source) sibling DexGuard (android, closed source) does string encryption.

See: https://www.guardsquare.com/en/dexguard

Let me also add that the proguard page also list a lot of other(!) obfuscators: https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard#alternatives.html

Comment: I' ve seen this actually, but I want a tool that can also be used for our Java projects. Besides, I couldn' t find any trial or demo version of DexGuard, so can I trust the security it provides? What do you think? Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry haven't used it myself, their other software, Proguard, works really well though on both android apps and normal java programs. Trust is a strong word when it comes to security. It will make it very difficult, I doubt impossible.

Comment: [Stringer](https://jfxstore.com/stringer) (commercial) works for both Java and Android.

Answer (score 10):

Some of the Obfuscator are,

### [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)

ProGuard is a free Java class file shrinker and obfuscator. It can detect and remove unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes. It can then rename the remaining classes, fields, and methods using short meaningless names. The resulting jars are smaller and harder to reverse-engineer.

### [yGuard](http://www.yworks.com/products/yguard)

yGuard is an improved version of RetroGuard that comes with an ant task.

### [JODE](http://jode.sourceforge.net/)

JODE is a java package containing a decompiler and an optimizer for java. The optimizer transforms class files in various ways with can be controlled by a script file. It supports the following operations:

- Renaming class, method, field and local names to shorter, obfuscated, or unique names or according to a given translation table
- Removing debugging information
- Removing dead code (classes, fields, methods) and constant fields
- Optimizing local variable allocation

### [JavaGuard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaguard/)

JavaGuard is a general purpose bytecode obfuscator, designed to fit effortlessly into your regular build and testing process, providing peace of mind that your valuable Java code is more secure against decompilation and other forms of reverse engineering.

### [jarg](http://jarg.sourceforge.net/)

The jarg reduces the size of a jar file in which java class files are stored. "Size curtailment can be carried out simply" is the 1st target. However, as a result of processing by jarg, since a Java class file is optimized, it becomes quicker, and since it is renamed, it becomes that it is harder to be analyzed. That is, jarg is 'Java Optimizer', and it is 'Java Obfuscator' and is also 'Java Shrinker' or 'Java Reducer'.

Comment: @DmitryLeskov What was your reasoning for removing an entire section of someone else's answer? I'm surprised the edit was approved, because unless I'm missing something, whatever your issue is with that section should have been posted as a comment instead. Please explain.

Comment: @AdiInbar I've removed a dead link. That product (RetroGuard) is long gone.